# determining circle-color with nested expressions

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use a GeoJSON as my source, where every entity has a state.
I want to draw circles for every entity, where the circle color is based on the state, and whether the circle has been clicked or not.

Determining the "clicked-state" is done via `setFeatureState()` where a feature receives the "click" state when clicked.

I tried to first check for the click state and match the state, based on the feature being clicked or not:

```
    "circle-color": [
        'case',
        ['boolean',
            ['feature-state', 'click'],
            false,
        ],
        ['match',          //Feature clicked = true
            ['get', 'state'],
            'SOME_FEATURE_STATE_STRING',
            '#57E757',  // possible match
            'SOME_OTHER_FEATURE_STATE_STRING',
            '#123456',  // possible match

            '#123456' //fallback
        ],
        '#001ebe'           //Feature clicked = false
    ]
```

The "unclicked" circle has the correct color. However, when I click the circle, the circle-color is changed to black and not my "match" color.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `case` expression is incorrect here :

```js
['boolean', 
  ['feature-state', 'click'],
  false,
],
```

You have used the [boolean](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#types-boolean) types expression, which is a [type](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#types) expression (it asserts that the input value is a boolean).

In your case, you want to use a [decision](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#decision) expression.

With the [`==`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#==) operator, you can return `true` if the input values are equal, `false` otherwise.

Your `case` expression would become :

```js
"circle-color": [
 'case',
 ['==', ['feature-state', 'click'], true],
 ['match',     // Feature clicked = true
   ['get', 'state'],
   'SOME_FEATURE_STATE_STRING',
   '#57E757',  // Possible match
   
   'SOME_OTHER_FEATURE_STATE_STRING',
   '#123456',  // Possible match
   
   '#123456'   // Fallback
 ],
 '#001ebe'     // Feature clicked = false
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! You are right, a decision expression makes a lot more sense here. I accept your answer. 
Do you happen to know if the ```get``` expression can be used for nested objects? Let's say state is an object and I want to get a property of that object.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve a nested property by calling multiple times the [`get`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#get) function (`["get", string, object]: value`) and specifying the `object` in the third argument, for example `['get', 'nested', ['get', 'state']]` to get `state.nested`.